# Existing string/array containing different character types in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

So I have a small string (char array) in C and I would like to see what kind of characters are in there (uppercase, lowercase, digits, special characters, or whitespace... not so much whitespace, but just in case another poor soul comes along and finds this let's say whitespace). The first method that came to mind is how it can be done in Python, which is by using the string.digits and string.uppercase and stuff like that to see if any character in my string is a digit or a lowercase or anything like that. However, I haven't been able to find the same thing in C.

Is there something in the standard C libraries that gives me a list (array/string) of all the uppercase or lowercase or digits or special characters on in the ascii table? I've looked in `<string.h>`, but not much luck.

Comment: Note: I could create my own strings, but I was wondering if the C standard library already had something that would make my work easier.

Comment: So.. have you actually looked at what C standard library is providing?

Comment: No, there is no such thing. You have to write if yourself.

Comment: You can test single characters using the `<ctype.h>` functions.

Comment: @Deathsbreed - Didn't any of the below answers helped? If there is any query, please feel free to ask below the answer posts.

Comment: @Deathsbreed - If my answer helped, you may like to upvote, OR, even accept the answer. If there is any query, please feel free to ask below the answer post!

Answer (score 0):

There's no "do-it-all" kind of functions in C. But there are standard functions, exposed via the header [`<ctype.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isalpha.3.html) provides various standard functions (declarations) which you could use for this purpose.

Using a loop and some of the following functions, you can achieve that.

```
   #include <ctype.h>

   int isalnum(int c);
   int isalpha(int c);
   int iscntrl(int c);
   int isdigit(int c);
   int isgraph(int c);
   int islower(int c);
   int isprint(int c);
   int ispunct(int c);
   int isspace(int c);
   int isupper(int c);
   int isxdigit(int c);

   int isascii(int c);
   int isblank(int c);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something in the standard C libraries that gives me a list
> (array/string) of all the uppercase or lowercase or digits or special
> characters on in the ascii table?

C has a character handling library, `<ctype.h>`. This character-handling library *(`<ctype.h>`)* includes several functions that perform useful tests and manipulations of character data.

You can check for several tests on a per-character basis using functions included in the `<ctype.h>`  library.

> **int isblank( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a blank
> character that separates words in a line of text and 0 (false)
> otherwise. [Note: This func- tion is not available in Microsoft Visual
> C++.]
>
> **int isdigit( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a digit and 0
> (false) otherwise.
>
> **int isalpha( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a letter and 0
> otherwise.
>
> **int isalnum( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a digit or a
> letter and 0 otherwise.
>
> **int isxdigit( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a hexadecimal
> digit character and 0 otherwise.
>
> **int islower( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a lowercase
> letter and 0 otherwise.
>
> **int isupper( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is an uppercase
> letter and 0 otherwise.
>
> **int tolower( int c )** ---> If c is an uppercase
> letter, tolower returns c as a lowercase letter. Otherwise, tolower
> returns the argument unchanged.
>
> **int toupper( int c )** ---> If c is a lowercase letter, toupper returns
> c as an uppercase letter. Otherwise, toupper returns the argument
> unchanged.
>
> **int isspace( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a whitespace
> character—newline ( '\n' ), space ( ' ' ), form feed ( '\f' ),
> carriage return ( '\r' ), horizontal tab ( '\t' ) or vertical tab (
> '\v' )—and 0 otherwise.
>
> **int iscntrl( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a control
> character and 0 otherwise.
>
> **int ispunct( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a printing
> character other than a space, a digit, or a letter and returns 0
> otherwise.
>
> **int isprint( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a printing
> character including a space and returns 0 otherwise.
>
> **int isgraph( int c )** ---> Returns a true value if c is a printing
> character other than a space and returns 0 otherwise.